# how to set a dependency for two scopes?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a dependency which I need to use it both in server and Jenkins server. And I need scope 'provided' and 'test'.

The current setting is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Can I change it to the following and how can I make it work?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
        <scope>provided,test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

A dependency can have just one scope.

Provided dependencies are automatically on the test class path, so setting the scope to provided is fine.